# Keyboard interrupt, sockets and Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets

I'm working on an interface that communicates using sockets. I need to use Threads in order to receive and send data at the same time.

The below code is a cut down version of the module that continuously sends data.

My issue is that during development, I need to start and stop this frequently, but it seems threads makes it impossible to stop the application like you can a normal script. The process needs to be killed in process manager in order to restart it.

I have a feeling I am misunderstanding something.

I've looked around but I'm seeing loads of inconsistent answers which I've tried to implement to no avail. I've tried handling the KeyboardInterrupt exception and that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

```
import socket
import sys
import threading

running = True
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ('localhost', 50000)
print ('connecting to %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.connect(server_address)

class TelemetryPacket:
    state = "N/A" 

    def __init__(self, stringvalue):
        self.state = stringvalue

    def serialise(self):
        return "%s" % (self.state)

def send(running):
    try:
        while (running):
            telemetry = TelemetryPacket(0).serialise()
            sock.sendto(telemetry.encode('utf-8'), server_address)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("threads successfully closed")
        running = False

def recv(running):
    try:
        while (running):
            data = sock.recv(1)
            if (data):
                print("data received: %s" % data)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("threads successfully closed")
        running = False

a = threading.Thread(target=send, args=(running,))
a.start()

b = threading.Thread(target=recv, args=(running,))
b.start()
```

Comment: `sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` AND **I need to use Threads in order to receive and send data at the same time** First, learn about the socket library. You cannot write a real time application with a TCP connection!

Comment: @dsgdfg You make a good point. I assumed there was only one type of "socket", so I assumed this library was all UDP, without really thinking.

This is only a prototype though, so it's fine for now. I'll definitely look into a proper solution later, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be capturing your your keyboard interrupt in the main thread and then sending a signal to your child threads to exit and join back to the main thread. You should also use something more thread safe for signaling like the basic `threading.Event()`, so:

```
import threading
import time

exit_signal = threading.Event()  # your global exit signal

def send():
    while not exit_signal.is_set():
        pass  # whatever you need

def recv():
    while not exit_signal.is_set():
        pass  # whatever you need

# create the threads
a = threading.Thread(target=send)
b = threading.Thread(target=recv)

# start the threads
a.start()
b.start()

# create a main thread loop
try:
    while not exit_signal.is_set():  # enable children threads to exit the main thread, too
        time.sleep(0.1)  # let it breathe a little
except KeyboardInterrupt:  # on keyboard interrupt...
    exit_signal.set()  # send signal to all listening threads

# join back the threads
a.join()
b.join()

# and you're done...
```

Comment: This is a very nice answer. I think I understand this a lot more now, and the structure is a lot cleaner than the way I was doing it since there's only one try/catch, and it uses the event instead of a bool. 
I just had to add a socket.close() in the exception handler, and now it works as I expect! 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that on keyboard exception only the main thread is killed.
So you need to notify the threads that the main thread has been killed.

Instead of passing the running as an argument, use it to signal the threads.Here is an example code. Only difference is that function doesn't take running as an argument but it uses it to keep track. So when the main thread dies, we set it to false(at the end of the code).

```
import socket
import sys
import threading


running = True
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server_address = ('localhost', 50000)
print ('connecting to %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.bind(server_address)

class TelemetryPacket:
    state = "N/A" 

    def __init__(self, stringvalue):
        self.state = stringvalue

    def serialise(self):
        return "%s" % (self.state)

def send():
    try:
        while (running):
            telemetry = TelemetryPacket(0).serialise()
            sock.sendto(telemetry.encode('utf-8'), server_address)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("threads successfully closed")


def recv():
    try:
        while (running):
            data = sock.recv(1)
            if (data):
                print("data received: %s" % data)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("threads successfully closed")

try:
    a = threading.Thread(target=send)
    a.start()

    b = threading.Thread(target=recv)
    b.start()

    while True:
        pass

except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("threads successfully closed")
        running = False # Kill the threads
```

Comment: Thanks, thinking catching the interrupt at the highest level helped me understand the threading issue. I also had to add a socket.close() for it to work nicely.