# How do I add a timeout to multiprocessing.connection.Client(..) in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, multiprocessing, python-3.7

I've got two Python programs running. Program A connects to program B with the **multiprocessing** module:

```py
# Connection code in program A
# -----------------------------
import multiprocessing
import multiprocessing.connection

...

connection = multiprocessing.connection.Client(
('localhost', 19191),                # <- address of program B
authkey='embeetle'.encode('utf-8')   # <- authorization key
)

...

connection.send(send_data)

recv_data = connection.recv()
```

It works perfectly most of the time. However, sometimes program B is frozen (the details don't matter much, but it usually happens when the GUI from program B spawns a modal window).
While program B is frozen, program A hangs at the following line:

```py
connection = multiprocessing.connection.Client(
('localhost', 19191),                # <- address of program B
authkey='embeetle'.encode('utf-8')   # <- authorization key
)
```

It keeps waiting for a response. I would like to put a **timeout** parameter, but the call to `multiprocessing.connection.Client(..)` does not have one.

How can I implement a timeout here?

**Notes:**
I'm working on a `Windows 10` computer with `Python 3.7`.

Comment: [`.Client` is a function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#L483).  Answers to [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call) delineate a number of methods (there are other similar SO Q&A's reachable with a search). Many methods involve decorators; if one is useful, you could wrap/redefine `.Client` with it -  `Client = timeout_decorator(...Client)`  and use the wrapped function.

Comment: If you think that your question is a duplicate to [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call) please comment so we can mark it as such.

Comment: Hi @wwii , the **Timeout on a function call** is indeed a very good approach to this! Thanks a lot. However, I noticed the accepted answer at that question is for UNIX only. What do you consider to be the best answer for Windows users?

Comment: caveat: I have no practical experience with this other than playing with stuff I find here on SO.  I think I would try using this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31667005/2823755. It uses `threading.Timer` to raise `KeyboardInterrupt` that could be caught.  It would be nice to have a minimal working example to play around with: something that mimics your Programs A and B that try to connect with each other and nothing much else - to make sure that doing this with `multiprocessing.connection.Client` doesn't cause any unwanted side effects.

Comment: Specifically - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871191/cant-close-socket-on-keyboardinterrupt-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847392/keyboard-interrupt-sockets-and-threads.  Might need something more elaborate using https://stackoverflow.com/a/31667005/2823755 as a starting point.

Comment: can you add also the code for program B ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I would like to put a timeout parameter, but the call to `multiprocessing.connection.Client(..)` does not have one. How can I implement a timeout here?

Looking at the [source to multiprocessing.connection in Python 3.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bccacd19fa7b56dcf2fbfab15992b6b94ab6666b/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py), the `Client()` function is a fairly brief wrapper around `SocketClient()` for your use case, which in turn wraps `Connection()`.

At first it looked fairly straightforward to write a `ClientWithTimeout` wrapper that does the same thing, but additionally calls `settimeout()` on the socket it creates for the connection. However, this does not have the correct effect, because:

1. Python implements its own socket timeout behaviour by using `select()` and an underlying non-blocking OS socket; this behaviour is what is configured by `settimeout()`.
2. `Connection` operates directly on an OS socket handle, which is returned by calling `detach()` on the normal Python socket object.
3. Since Python has set the OS socket handle to the non-blocking mode, `recv()` calls on it return immediately rather than waiting for the timeout period.

However, we can still set a receive timeout on the underlying OS socket handle by using the low-level `SO_RCVTIMEO` socket option.

Hence the second version of my solution:

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Connection, answer_challenge, deliver_challenge
import socket, struct

def ClientWithTimeout(address, authkey, timeout):

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET) as s:
        s.setblocking(True)
        s.connect(address)

        # We'd like to call s.settimeout(timeout) here, but that won't work.

        # Instead, prepare a C "struct timeval" to specify timeout. Note that
        # these field sizes may differ by platform.
        seconds = int(timeout)
        microseconds = int((timeout - seconds) * 1e6)
        timeval = struct.pack("@LL", seconds, microseconds)

        # And then set the SO_RCVTIMEO (receive timeout) option with this.
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVTIMEO, timeval)

        # Now create the connection as normal.
        c = Connection(s.detach())

    # The following code will now fail if a socket timeout occurs.

    answer_challenge(c, authkey)
    deliver_challenge(c, authkey)

    return c
```

For brevity, I have assumed the parameters are as per your example, i.e.:

- address is a tuple (implying address family is `AF_INET`).
- authkey is a byte string.

If you need to handle cases where these assumptions don't hold then you will need to copy a little more logic from `Client()` and `SocketClient()`.

Although I looked at the `multiprocessing.connection` source to find out how to do this, my solution does not use any private implementation details. `Connection`, `answer_challenge` and `deliver_challenge` are all public and documented parts of the API. This function should therefore be be safe to use with future versions of `multiprocessing.connection`.

Note that `SO_RCVTIMEO` may not be supported on all platforms, but it is present on at least Windows, Linux and OSX. The format of `struct timeval` is also platform-specific. I have assumed that the two fields are always of the native `unsigned long` type. I think this should be correct on common platforms but it is not guaranteed to always be so. Unfortunately Python does not currently provide a platform-independent way to do this.

Below is a test program which shows this working - it assumes the above code is saved as `client_timeout.py`.

```
from multiprocessing.connection import Client, Listener
from client_timeout import ClientWithTimeout
from threading import Thread
from time import time, sleep

addr = ('localhost', 19191)
key = 'embeetle'.encode('utf-8')

# Provide a listener which either does or doesn't accept connections.
class ListenerThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, accept):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.accept = accept

    def __enter__(self):
        if self.accept:
            print("Starting listener, accepting connections")
        else:
            print("Starting listener, not accepting connections")
        self.active = True 
        self.start()
        sleep(0.1)

    def run(self):
        listener = Listener(addr, authkey=key)
        self.active = True
        if self.accept:
            listener.accept()
        while self.active:
            sleep(0.1)
        listener.close()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.active = False
        self.join()
        print("Stopped listener")
        return True

for description, accept, name, function in [
        ("ClientWithTimeout succeeds when the listener accepts connections.",
        True, "ClientWithTimeout", lambda: ClientWithTimeout(addr, timeout=3, authkey=key)),
        ("ClientWithTimeout fails after 3s when listener doesn't accept connections.",
        False, "ClientWithTimeout", lambda: ClientWithTimeout(addr, timeout=3, authkey=key)),
        ("Client succeeds when the listener accepts connections.",
        True, "Client", lambda: Client(addr, authkey=key)),
        ("Client hangs when the listener doesn't accept connections (use ctrl-C to stop).",
        False, "Client", lambda: Client(addr, authkey=key))]:

    print("Expected result:", description)

    with ListenerThread(accept):
        start_time = time()
        try:
            print("Creating connection using %s... " % name)
            client = function()
            print("Client created:", client)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed:", e)
        print("Time elapsed: %f seconds" % (time() - start_time))

    print()
```

Running this on Linux produces the following output:

```
Expected result: ClientWithTimeout succeeds when the listener accepts connections.
Starting listener, accepting connections
Creating connection using ClientWithTimeout... 
Client created: <multiprocessing.connection.Connection object at 0x7fad536884e0>
Time elapsed: 0.003276 seconds
Stopped listener

Expected result: ClientWithTimeout fails after 3s when listener doesn't accept connections.
Starting listener, not accepting connections
Creating connection using ClientWithTimeout... 
Failed: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
Time elapsed: 3.157268 seconds
Stopped listener

Expected result: Client succeeds when the listener accepts connections.
Starting listener, accepting connections
Creating connection using Client... 
Client created: <multiprocessing.connection.Connection object at 0x7fad53688c50>
Time elapsed: 0.001957 seconds
Stopped listener

Expected result: Client hangs when the listener doesn't accept connections (use ctrl-C to stop).
Starting listener, not accepting connections
Creating connection using Client... 
^C
Stopped listener
```

Comment: Did you test it? If possible and not too lengthy could you add the code for testing it?

Comment: Excellent, thnx for the extra. Hopefully OP will be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks, this helped loads! I tweaked this a little and 1) added a send timeout (as this could block just as well), and 2) set both options before `s.connect` (as this is the blocking function when sending).
You can set the send timeout similarly: `s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDTIMEO, timeval)`